# How to automatically open a file if closed in python

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7

I'm starting python and I wrote a basic program to open a pdf file but if I close the pdf then I have to launch the program again to open the pdf, what I want is to reopen the pdf automatically if closed unless I close the console

Comment: what command do you use to open?

Comment: I use open() though I could use os.startfile if I import os

Comment: are u using windows?

Comment: You can create an infinite loop and use `psutil` to check if the process is running, if it isn't you call the `.open()` again.

Comment: Yeah I am using windows

Comment: How exactly would i use psutil sorry I'm still a noob

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/psutil-module-in-python/   use this link to know about psutil